# reactjs iterate over a array in functional component

Tags: reactjs

I have a array of employee objects and i'm using that array(passed as state) to build rows in a table(as shown below). I get this error while iterating over the array. when I display the array using {props.employee_data}(the line is commented)

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
```

Code:

```
export default function(props) {
    let employees = null    
    return (            
        <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>       
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Current Annual Salary</th>
            <th>2018 Gross Pay Received</th>
            <th>2018 Overtime Pay</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Department Name</th>
            <th>Division</th>
            <th>Assignment Category</th>
            <th>Employee Position Title</th>
            <th>Position Under-filled</th>
            <th>Date First Hired</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {/* <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
           */}
           {/* {props.employee_data} */}
          {props.employee_data.map((employee)=>{
            return <tr>employee</tr>
          }
          )}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    )
  }
```

parent component

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      employee_data: null,
      column_names: null
    }
}

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {          
      fetch(county_data).
        then(response => response.json()).
        then(response => {
          console.log(response.data)
          let column_names = response.meta.view.columns.map((item)=>{
            return item['name']
          })
          // console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))

          this.setState({
            employee_data: response.data,
            column_names: column_names
          })          
        })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col lg={4}>1 of 3</Col>
            <Col lg={4}>2 of 3</Col>
            <Col lg={4}>2 of 3</Col>
          </Row>          
        </Container>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <DataTable employee_data={this.state.employee_data}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Im actually not using employees anywhere. commented it out, still same error

Comment: ok then please post your parent component code

Comment: added the parent component as well

Comment: try changing `employee_data: null` to `employee_data: []`

Comment: ill post this as an answer why it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially the `employee_data` is null, it is not until your `fetch`, the employee data is an array.

`map` is a function on the array's prototype, hence it will not be available on the initial `employee_data` which is null. Only after the `fetch`, the employee data is an array and the `map` function is available.

To get around this, you can initially declare `employee_data` as an empty array.

```
this.state = {
  employee_data: [],
  ... other state data,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do th
`export default function(props) {
    let employees = props.employee_data?props.employee_data:[];

    return (

        <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>

            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Current Annual Salary</th>
            <th>2018 Gross Pay Received</th>
            <th>2018 Overtime Pay</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Department Name</th>
            <th>Division</th>
            <th>Assignment Category</th>
            <th>Employee Position Title</th>
            <th>Position Under-filled</th>
            <th>Date First Hired</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {/* <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
           */}
           {/* {props.employee_data} */}
          {employees.map((employee)=>{
            return <tr>employee</tr>
          }
          )}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    )
  }`